# ClassNotFoundException for ViewModelProviders inside aar library

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components

i'm building a library that contains multiple activities.

I'm using the new architecture components, in gradle

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

If i compile it as an app everything works fine

When i tried to test the implementation of my library in an app it its throwing a exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders"
```

Looks like its not including the dependency inside the aar package.

Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**

I'm seeing that if i include the same dependencies my library is using in the app proyect it's working but those dependencies are only used in my component and i can't know if the target app is going to have them.

**Is there any way to make this work without having to include the same dependencies again in the target app?**

Comment: don't you use any specific exclude rules in your module-level build.gradle file for tests?

Comment: No i'm not using any

Comment: seems that the compiled class cannot be found during tests run (after search that depends on CLASSPATH variable), but it works okay after compilation with android lifecycle. I had such an issue when JNI that were transitively used in tests were dependent on Android platform, so no appropriate `*.so` files were available for plain computers...

Comment: a possible workaround is to transform unit tests that are being run on a computer into instrumented tests, if it is acceptable

Comment: this has nothing to do with tests...

Comment: oh, sorry. "When i tried to test the implementation of my library in an app it its throwing a exception:" - i thought it appeared when you ran your test suite

Comment: Are you minifying library code??

Comment: @Sunny no, and im trying with the debug version

Comment: Try to replace implementation with api.

Comment: @Sunny i've tried and nothing changes... the only way this is working is including the same dependencies again in the target app.